# css and div, how to fix text always vertically positioned at top

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML and CSS, where stackoverflow kindly gave guidance to create it.
However the small text on the right appears vertically positioned at the top of the prior larger font.
No matter what I try, it stays that way.
Suggestions welcomed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a_list">
     <div id="a01" class="highlight_on_hover">
       <div class="lineitem">
          <div class="lineitem_lefttext">left text</div><div class="lineitem_righttext">right text</div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

#a_list {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
.highlight_on_hover {
  color:black;
}
.highlight_on_hover:hover {
  color:red;
}
.lineitem {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  vertical-align: center;
}
.lineitem_lefttext {
  /*background-color: green;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: large;
}
.lineitem_lefttext:after {
  content: " ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................";
  vertical-align: center;
}
.lineitem_righttext {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-size: xx-small;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want the right text to be like? What are you trying to do?

Comment: ok, I hoped for:  left text, dots "as usual" vertically positioned at the bottom of the left text, right text centred vertically compared to the left text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `.lineitem_righttext` with `font-size:xx-small;` its `top-margin` and `top-padding` is also small down so the text is stuck upper side. You can set `top-margin` and `top-padding` to take down the text. Or by simply make the `font-size:large;` to align with the left text.

Comment: Thank you.  This appears to be it.  I guess I'll have to look into how much padding is needed if I want a smaller font size.

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

If you mean why it always stays right and not front of other `div` then you need to remove `justify-content: space-between;` in flex `div`.

`space-between:` items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the **start line**, last item on the **end line**.

```css
#a_list {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: black;
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.highlight_on_hover {
  color:black;
}
.highlight_on_hover:hover {
  color:red;
}
.lineitem {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: center;
  
}
.lineitem_lefttext {
 margin:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: large;
}
.lineitem_lefttext:after {
  content: " ";
  vertical-align: center;
}
.lineitem_righttext {
 margin:10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-size: xx-small;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="a_list">
     <div id="a01" class="highlight_on_hover">
       <div class="lineitem">
          <div class="lineitem_lefttext">left text</div><div class="lineitem_righttext">right text</div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you.  I hoped for: left text, dots "as usual" vertically positioned at the bottom of the left text, right text centred vertically compared to the left text.

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
<div class="lineitem_righttext">right text</div>
```

working solution 1:

```
<div class="lineitem_righttext"><p>right text</p></div>
```

explanation:

the `vertical-align: center;` centers the objects inside it, the `right text` is only text and can't be read as object, placing it inside object like `<p>` works.

Comment: thank you.the unexpected result (in jsfiddle) was that the right text became centred on the dots rather than the left text. So, left text then dots at the bottom of the left text, then right text centred on the dots.  I was hoping for the right text to be centred in relation to the left text.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link maybe its helpful fr yu..

[Example link](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/ga8bwhjo/)

```css
#a_list {
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: black;
}

.highlight_on_hover {
  color: black;
}

.highlight_on_hover:hover {
  color: red;
}

.lineitem {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: center;

}

.lineitem_lefttext {
  margin: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: large;
}

.lineitem_lefttext:after {
  content: " ";
  vertical-align: center;
}

.lineitem_righttext {
  margin: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  font-size: small;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you, yes it is a helpful link.  I'll look into jsfiddle.